# Controlling exponential spawning of go routines

Tags: multithreading, go

I am building a system where when a server receives a request it has to do some computations in sync and some computations in async, dont want to wait for async computations, rather do sync computations trigger go routine for async computations, return response.

Problem here is every request will be spawning a go routine here.

How can I limit the number of go routines?

```
func main() {
    serverRequest()
}

type data struct {
    a int
    b bool
}

func serverRequest() {
    d := syncWork()
    go asyncWork(d)
    // return api response
}

func syncWork() data {
    return data {
        10,
        false,
    }
}

func asyncWork(d data) {
    // making network calls with data d
}
```

Is there a way in current scenario I limit the number of go routines spawned?

Answer (score 2):

Worker pool ( like thread pool ) is another solution to limit the number of concurrent work to a fixed size, here is an example from [gobyexample](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools). For your case, it become something like this:

```golang
func main() {
    serverRequest()
}

type data struct {
    a int
    b bool
}

func serverRequest() {
    jobs := make(chan data)
    workersCount := 5

    for i :=0; i < workersCount; i++ {
        go asyncWorkWorker(jobs)
    }

    d := syncWork()
    jobs <- d
    // remember to block the call
    // return api response
}

func syncWork() data {
    return data {
        10,
        false,
    }
}

func asyncWorkWorker(jobs <-chan data) {
    for job := range jobs {
        asyncWork(job)
    }
}

func asyncWork(d data) {
    // making network calls with data d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of goroutines using a buffered channel as a semaphore:

```
var requestSem= make(chan struct{},limit)

func serverRequest() {
    d := syncWork()
    requestSem<-struct{}{}
    go func() {
      defer func() { <-requestSem }
      asyncWork(d)
    }()
    // return api response
}
```

This will block the `serverRequest` function before starting a new goroutine if there are already `limit` of them running.